# AWS CodeBuild Provisioning failing

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild, dockerhub

My dockerfile on local is working fine, I pushed the code to github and then configured a CodePipeline but it fails in the CodeBuild stage.

I am not using AWS ECR but DockerHub, currently it fails in CodeBuild provisioning step with following error:

`BUILD_CONTAINER_UNABLE_TO_PULL_IMAGE: Unable to pull customer's container image. CannotPullContainerError: Error response from daemon: manifest for dipuvish5/nest_api_server:latest not found: manifest unknown: manifest unknown`

**My buildspec.yml is saved in github repository root folder and is as follows**:

```
env:
  variables:
    DOCKERHUB_USERNAME: "*******"
    IMAGE_REPO_NAME: "nest_api_server"
    IMAGE_TAG:  "latest"
    DOCKERHUB_PASS: "*******"

phases:
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Docker Hub...
      - docker login --username $DOCKERHUB_USERNAME --password $DOCKERHUB_PASS
      
  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...          
      - docker build -t $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG .
      - docker tag $IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG $DOCKERHUB_USERNAME/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
      
  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker image...
      - docker push $DOCKERHUB_USERNAME/$IMAGE_REPO_NAME:$IMAGE_TAG
```

Kindly ignore docker password in the buidspec.yml, here we are deliberately using password in file as its a temporary project and needs to be deleted in few days and it does not contain any important details